# R wordcloud2 not putting the most frequent words on edges

Tags: r, wordcloud2

I would like to use the wordcloud2 function in R on my dataset.
The demo works nice:
[image: demo image from the library docs]

But my dataset centers the small text in the middle.
Any ideas/suggestions (includning other R libraries) welcomed:)

[image: my dataset]

Thank you very much
**Vladimir Vinarsky**
*The curious Mechanobiologist*

I expected my higherst frequency words in the middle, not in the edges.
Tried to

1. manipulate the frequencies distribution by squaring it or making a power of 3
2. tried more shapes

Comment: Perhaps if you include your code in the question we might know how to fix it?

Comment: Thanks I am just using the default parameters: `wordcloud2(my_data, size=0.3)` (reduced size as it does not fit into the plot). I cannot upload the dataset as it is research data we have not published. Will try to replace the word column with some random words to be able to upload it.
Surprisingly enough the wordcloud() pacakge works in the sense that the most frequent are in the center

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Words at the top of your data frame are plotted centrally; those at the bottom are plotted peripherally, so if you want the big words in the middle, sort your data frame accordingly.

For example, let's generate a data frame of computing terms with a random frequency column:

```r
my_data <- data.frame(word = c("Algorithm", "Function", "Variable",
  "Loop", "Object", "Class", "Inheritance", "Interface", "Array", 
  "String", "Integer", "Boolean", "Compiler", "Debugger", "Syntax",
  "Exception", "Library", "Framework", "API", "Database", "Query", 
  "Server", "Client", "Protocol", "Encryption", "Binary", "Source",
  "IDE", "Repository", "Recursion", "Data", "Pointer", "Stack", "Queue", 
  "Tree", "Graph", "Hash", "Encryption", "Bit", "Byte", "Bandwidth", 
  "Cache", "Cloud", "Compiler", "Constant", "Debug", "Deployment",
  "DNS", "Domain", "Email", "Firewall", "Gateway", "Git", "Hardware",
  "HTTP", "HTTPS", "IP Address", "JSON", "Kernel", "LAN", "Metadata",
  "Multithreading", "Network", "Node", "Packet", "Patch", "Pixel",
  "Platform", "Plugin"))

set.seed(1)
my_data$freq <- round(rnorm(nrow(my_data), 10, 3)^2)
```

If I plot without ordering at all, I get a fairly random distribution of sizes throughout the cloud:

```r
wordcloud2::wordcloud2(my_data, size = 0.3)
```

[image]

If I sort from small to large, I can replicate your issue with the smaller words appearing in the middle of the image:

```r
wordcloud2::wordcloud2(my_data[order(my_data$freq),], size = 0.3)
```

[image]

If I sort in reverse order, I get the desired output, with the larger words drawn in the middle before smaller words are added around and between the larger words:

```r
wordcloud2::wordcloud2(my_data[rev(order(my_data$freq)),], size = 0.3)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you:)
This works :)
I was trying to achieve the same with `data%>% arrange(freq)` but messed up the sorting order, now I know it should be `data%>% arrange(desc(freq))`